# How to create multiple conditions on Listener Rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb

I'm tryng to create a listener rule with two different conditions and i got error all the time.

```
    "ListenerRule": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule",
      "Properties": {
          "Actions": [
                    {
                     "Type": "forward",
                     "TargetGroupArn": {
                     "Ref": "SwaggBOTG"
                    }
            }
           ],
       "Conditions": [
                    {
                        "Field": "query-string",
                        "QueryStringConfig": {
                            "Values": [
                                {
                                    "Key": "app",
                                    "Value": "two"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "Field" : "path-pattern",
                        "PathPatternConfig": {
                            "Values" : [ "/one/*" ]
                        }
                    }
        ],
```

I need two different condition. One of them should be a query-string type and the another one a path-pathern type. I got to create only creating one of them, but i'm not able to create both.

The error is the next:

```
You cannot specify 'QueryStringConfig' for actions of type 'path-pattern' (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancingV2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError;
```

I think that is something of the syntax, but i didn't found the problem..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that `Conditions` is a list of separate conditions. You should have 2 separate items in that list in your case. If you take a closer look at your json, you can see that you are defining `Field` two times at the same level. The second one `"Field" : "path-pattern"` overrides the first one `"Field": "query-string"`, therefore the error tells you that you can't define `'QueryStringConfig'` for `"PathPatternConfig"` simply because you can't do that.

Here is the correct definition of `Conditions`.

```
"Conditions": [
    {
        "Field": "path-pattern",
        "PathPatternConfig": {
            "Values": ["/one/*"]
        }
    },
    {
        "Field": "query-string",
        "QueryStringConfig": {
            "Values": [
                {
                    "Value": "two",
                    "Key": "app"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: So it's not posible to define two conditions in the same listener rule?

Comment: It is possible. That whole document defines just one listener rule. Look at your top level object, it is called `ListenerRule` (single listener rule, not many)

Comment: i got similar error using your code: ```You cannot provide both Values and 'PathPatternConfig' for a condition of type 'path-pattern```.  Yes, i just want one ListenerRule, but with two conditions..

Comment: @hmar Fixed (191 days later)! There was a superfluous key/value pair in the first Condition.